# Is there an efficient/best way to assign scores to values in a pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a column of a dataframe with values for customer 'Length of Relationship'. I want to convert these values to numbers from 1-4 based on if they are below average for terminated relationship length, above average, above 1 standard deviation, and above 2 standard deviations. Without looping through using a for loop, is there an easier/faster way to do this?

Here is my code so far:

```
average = terminatedDf['Relationship Length'].mean()

standardDeviation = terminatedDf['Relationship Length'].std()

lorScores = {np.arange(0, average): 1, np.arange(average, standardDeviation): 2, np.arange(standardDeviation, standardDeviation*2): 3, np.arange(standardDeviation*2, 150): 4}

reportDf['Length of Relationship Score'] = reportDf['Relationship Length'].map(lorScores)
```

My problem is that numpy arrays are not hashable, but using the regular range function only allows for integers.

I suppose I could loop through the dataframe given that it is only ~ 1500 rows like this:

```
for row in reportDf:
    if row[5] < average: 
        row[15] = 1
    else:
     ....
```

I'm not sure even if I got the dictionary to work that .map would be any more efficient than the for loop. Is there a better way to do this? My intuition tells me this may just be an inefficient task to begin with. Here's a sample of what the Dataframe looks like, but it is actually downloaded from a salesforce API.

```
reportDf = ({'Owner': ['Bob', 'Jane', 'Alice', 'Fred'], 
             'Name': ['John', 'Johnny', 'Suzie', 'Larry']
             'Relationship Length': [0.78, 0.73, 19.36, 7.36]
             })
```

Average length is about 6.3 and standard deviation is about 3.4

Comment: Can you add your dataframe sample?

Comment: @SagunDevkota Yes, give me a minute to anonymize the data

Comment: Also either some of `terminatedDf` or the numerical values of `average` and `standardDeviation` with expected output of `resultDf` would be very helpful for testing purposes.

Comment: Additional question. What happens when the `average` is greater than `standardDeviation`?

Comment: @HenryEcker Good point, should have been average + standardDeviation. Didn't catch that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html#pandas-cut):

```
import pandas as pd

reportDf = pd.DataFrame({
    'Owner': ['Bob', 'Jane', 'Alice', 'Fred'],
    'Name': ['John', 'Johnny', 'Suzie', 'Larry'],
    'Relationship Length': [0.78, 0.73, 19.36, 7.36]
})

average = reportDf['Relationship Length'].mean()

standardDeviation = reportDf['Relationship Length'].std()

bins = [0, average, average + standardDeviation,
        average + (standardDeviation * 2), 150]
labels = [1, 2, 3, 4]

reportDf['Length of Relationship Score'] = pd.cut(
    reportDf['Relationship Length'],
    bins=bins,
    labels=labels,
    # right=False means upperbound non-inclusive
    # In the question you have row[5] < average
    # So this is set to use strictly less than
    # Remove if this is not the desired behaviour
    right=False
)

print(reportDf)
```

`reportDF`:

```
   Owner    Name  Relationship Length Length of Relationship Score
0    Bob    John                 0.78                            1
1   Jane  Johnny                 0.73                            1
2  Alice   Suzie                19.36                            3
3   Fred   Larry                 7.36                            2
```

Comment: Had never been introduced to .cut(). Thank you, this solved the issue and I can now use this for my other columns!

Answer (score 2):

I would create function for that and use [`pandas.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) following way

```
def get_score(x):
    if x <= average:
         return 1
    if average < x <= standardDeviation:
         return 2
    if standardDeviation < x <= standardDeviation*2:
         return 3
    if standardDeviation*2 < x <= 150:
         return 4

reportDf['Length of Relationship Score'] = reportDf['Relationship Length'].apply(get_score)
```

I do not know if it will be faster, but if your have 1500 rows or so, ultimate optimization might be not worth effort needed to implement it.

Edit: I found that there is [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) function made exactly for this task, lets say I want to divide numbers so 0...9 are "few", 10...99 are "tens" and rest undefined:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,9,10,17,45,99,100,121]})
df['category'] = pd.cut(df['x'], bins=[0,9,99], labels=['few','tens'])
print(df)
```

output

```
     x category
0    1      few
1    9      few
2   10     tens
3   17     tens
4   45     tens
5   99     tens
6  100      NaN
7  121      NaN
```

Comment: .cut() worked! Not sure what the best ettiquette is for accepting solutions as you and @HenryEcker both suggested it, but thank you

Answer (score 0):

Idk if you can do this with no loop at all, tbh.

But you should basically never go for raw loops like `for row in reportDf:`! They end up being super slow and there is always a better solution. E.g. iteritems() and list comprehensions. As this have multiple 'if' conditions I don't think it can be done in LC.

```
scores = []
for index, duration in terminatedDf['Relationship Length'].iteritems():
   if duration < average:
      scores.append(1)
   elif average < duration < average + standardDeviation:
      scores.append(2)
   elif average + standardDeviation < duration < average + 2*standardDeviation:
      scores.append(3)
   else:
      scores.append(4)

terminatedDf["Scores"] = scores
```